# List details of Azure Management Group from daemon application

Tags: azure, permissions, roles, azure-rbac

I have a daemon application that wants to list all subscriptions (incl. some details) within a management group in Azure.
For that I have created an `App registration` including client secrets in Azure to be used by the daemon application.
However, I am having now problems granting access to an entire management group.
What has worked, was to create a `Role assignment` (Type `App` -> Role `Reader`) for a single subscription. However, this does not work on management group level. There, I can only assign roles of type `User` to some roles. I cannot assign an `App` to a role.
How can I grant now the daemon application reader access to the entire management group?
(assigning individual subscriptions is not an option, because I want to see with that application for example if a subscription has been added)

Comment: Yes, thanks @JoyWang :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could follow the steps below.

1.Navigate to the Azure portal -> search for `management` -> click `Management groups`.

[image]

2.Choose the management group you want.

[image]

3.Click `(details)`.

[image]

4.Add the app(service principal) like below, in `Select`, search for your app name.

[image]